# Mesh Network detection using Python

Tags: python-3.x, wireshark, mesh, scapy, mesh-network

I have captured certain packets from a potential mesh networks, what all fields should I check in python using Scapy library so that to determine that the packets are indeed from a mesh network and not a traditional network.

I have tried investigating certain header fields such as baecon interval, broadcast, routing protocols etc. I captured packets using my wifi in monitor mode using aircrack-ng.

Let me know some fields which i can check in the pcapng file to determine the presence of a mesh network near me.